# Continue while loop after redirection

Tags: php, sms

I have a while loop in which I set a redirection to url having some variables. The code is as follows :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{

    $message = "Shri/Smt/Ms.  '".$row['1']."' , Your event '".$row['2']."' , '".$row['4']."' For CROA Sports 2018 is on '". $row['7']."'  at  ".$row['8'].":".$row['9']."";

    header("Location: http://10.31.*.*/smsrcroa.asp?B1=RPM&F_MB_TO=".$row['10']."&F_SMS_T=".$message."");
}
```

When this while loop run, it sends SMS to only first record and redirects to specified location. The while loop could not be continued. I wish to continue the while loop.

Comment: put the redirect outside and after the while loop

Comment: Can't work that way, a location redirect halts the script, that's the intended behavior. You have to use curl or file_get_contents with your SMS url

Comment: @AndreiAlexandru no, he wants to send multiple SMS so he has to call the SMS requests inside the loop. But another way

Comment: As Pierre said, use cURL, file_get_contents or work with AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redirecting use cURL which will call your URL without redirection. Here is function which can do that:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  return $data;
}
```

Than replace your `header(`... with `curl_get_contents(`...

If you call this function in your code it will look like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult))
{

    $message = "Shri/Smt/Ms.  '".$row['1']."' , Your event '".$row['2']."' , '".$row['4']."' For CROA Sports 2018 is on '". $row['7']."'  at  ".$row['8'].":".$row['9']."";

    curl_get_contents("http://10.31.*.*/smsrcroa.asp?B1=RPM&F_MB_TO=".$row['10']."&F_SMS_T=".$message."");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but its not working. Can you please give me the complete sample code ?

Comment: @AtulPatil added while loop with changed  function to original answer.

Comment: The url should not contain Location: . Try this: `curl_get_contents("http://10.31.*.*/smsrcroa.asp?B1=RPM&F_MB_TO=".$row['10']."&F_SMS_T=".$message."");`

Comment: Thanks. Removed Location from answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same as you also redirect from below url so that this will back in while loop

```
header("Location: http://10.31.*.*/smsrcroa.asp?B1=RPM&F_MB_TO=".$row['10']."&F_SMS_T=".$message."");
```

Comment: I don't think this URL is URL of script, so he isn't gonna lend back on script. But I might be wrong.